# How to disable default_scope for a belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to disable the `default_scope` for a single `belongs_to` association? The `default_scope` is fine for all but a single `belongs_to` that I would like to bypass the scope. I'm familiar with `with_exclusive_scope` however I don't think that can be used with belongs_to.

Any suggestions?

Context: I'm trying to allow the `branch_source` association in [acts_as_revisable](http://github.com/rich/acts_as_revisable) to point to a revision that is not the latest (`revisable_is_current` is false).

Answer (score 39):

Probably a bit late to the party (just short of 3 years), but just run into the same problem and the solution from Tobias is certainly the right direction, but it can be simplified for Rails 3.2+. The only thing I still don't like is the "hard coded" class name for Document, maybe it's possible to inflect using reflection...

Anyhow this is what I've come up with:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Document has some kind of default_scope
  belongs_to :document

  # Ensure document is not scoped, because Rails 3.2 uses modules it's
  # possible to use simple inheritance.
  def document
    Document.unscoped { super }
  end
end
```

*Update*: got a generic solution, based on reflect_on_association https://gist.github.com/2923336

Comment: The gist attached still works in 2021! (rails 6.1)

Comment: The gist attached is not working for me in rails 4.2.5

Answer (score 38):

```
belongs_to :account, -> { unscope(where: :destroyed_at) }
```

works for me, Rails 4.1

Comment: Is it possible to unscope all the conditions?

Comment: Great solution for Rails 4.1+, Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work if your default scope is a string / sql fragement

Comment: Looks like a fix for this is pending:
https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d25321b35328742ab97c08e7b1ed3cadeca5739b

Comment: This does not seem to work for Rails 5.  Also tried `-> { unscope(:deleted_at) }`, it does not work either.

Answer (score 15):

Just had this problem myself, and here's what I came up with:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :document # Document has some kind of default scope
                       # that stops us from finding it

  # Override getter method for document association
  def document_with_unscoped
    # Fetch document with default scope disabled
    Document.unscoped { document_without_unscoped }
  end
  alias_method_chain :document, :unscoped
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed this

```
belongs_to :document
```

and replaced it with

```
def document
    Document.unscope(where: :deleted_at).find_by(id: document_id)
end

def document=(d)
    self.document_id = d&.id
end
```