# Rails acts_as_paranoid and has_many :through

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, associations, acts-as-paranoid

So I'm using the rails3_acts_as_paranoid gem, and having some problems controlling scope with has_many :through associations.

For example

```
# User.rb
acts_as_paranoid
has_many :folders
has_many :files, :through => :folders
```

-

```
# Folder.rb
acts_as_paranoid
belongs_to :user
has_many :files, :dependent => :destroy
```

-

```
# File.rb
acts_as_paranoid
belongs_to :files
```

Now lets just say somewhere in the users_controller.rb i want to query all files belonging to a user, whether they are deleted, and/or belong to folders that have been deleted. So naturally I would assume to do something like the following

```
current_user.files.with_deleted
```

`with_deleted` method does it's job at removing the `files.deleted_at IS NULL`

**...BUT...** it doesnt remove the default_scope for folders which is used kind of behind the curtain. So we still have a `folders.deleted_at IS NULL` condition, preventing me from retrieving the files that belong to those folders where deleted_at is not null.

I want to keep using acts_as_paranoid, as it is incredibly useful in all other places of my app, and am trying not to do something like manual filtering and popping out elements of the `.where_values` array. But I don't know too much about handling complex scopes or what methods are available.

Comment: It seems the #unscoped method is what you're looking for here : http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/unscoped

Comment: I tried the unscoped method, but that drops the scope of automagic join bridging user to files, specifically `INNER JOIN folders ON files.folder_id = folders.id WHERE folders.user_id = 1` 
unless perhaps I missed a feature of unscoped to keep that?

Comment: I'm still checking if I find a solution, but just note that the line `@user = User.find current_user.id` is useless, as you're reloading the current_user

Comment: Ok updated it to be a little less useless :)

Comment: nice answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540645/how-to-disable-default-scope-for-a-belongs-to

Answer (score 12):

Well my question got down-voted, not sure why. But I found the answer:

When on a has_many through, the problem I was having was an inability to control the scope of the through model (Folders in this case).

Turns out you can just do this

```
@myvar = Folder.unscoped { current_user.files.with_deleted }
```

To whoever downvoted it - I'd like to know why, so I can ask better questions next time. Thanks!